# Rosetta Stone data on Dropbox

Tags: mac, dropbox, rosetta-stone

I'm currently trying to learn a new language using Rosetta Stone. Given that I have 2 computers (mac desktop and laptop), I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to have the data files in Dropbox so that I can synchronize my learning across computers.

Comment: If you can't put the data files in another folder (dropbox's one, typically), you will be interested by this other question, which is about the same issue (sharing files with dropbox, from arbitrary locations): http://superuser.com/questions/12555/to-share-files-at-arbitrary-locations-by-dropbox

Comment: I'm more specifically looking to see if anyone knows which files I have to put on Dropbox.

Comment: FYI, the tag "rosetta" could be confusing here since there is a Mac OS X technology which serves for executing PPC code on an Intel Apple computer and is also called Rosetta.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes you can (but there's a little more to it than dropping files in a folder):

Go to:

/Library/Application Support/Rosetta Stone Version 3

Edit dynamicStoredPaths.xml

BEFORE:

```
<localDatabasePath>/Library/Application Support/Rosetta Stone Version 3/tracking.db3</localDatabasePath>
```

AFTER

```
<localDatabasePath>/Users/USERNAME/Dropbox/Rosetta Stone v3/tracking.db3</localDatabasePath>
```

Note - Replace USERNAME with your home directory name.

Copy tracking.db3 to your dropbox location (note that above I created a 'Rosetta Stone v3' directory and copied it there).

You should be all set. (This is how I use it today - works well.)

You should save copies of the original files incase of any typos or errors.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data files can be placed inside the Dropbox folder, and are less than about 2GB (for the free version), then this should work fine.

Comment: minus.com will give you 10gb free, I think.